# How can I customize the Title in a .NET MAUI Flyout Shell app?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, maui-shell

[image: 1]

1. How to reduce the title spacing?
2. When I change hamburger icon, its icon color is always white. What's wrong?
3. Can I set Title font size and font family?

On Android it's possible to set `contentInsetLeft`, `contentInsetStart`, `contentInsetStartWithNavigation`.
But I don't know how to do this in .NET MAUI.

Comment: Custom Shell Renderer. If you are new, I advise against it. (Maybe Custom Tittle View...)

Answer (score 2):

## Custom TitleView

If you use the default MAUI app template, then you're using Shell and that allows you to set a custom TitleView:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.MyPage"
             Title="MyPage">

  <Shell.TitleView>
    <Grid>
      <Label 
        Text="Hello"
        HorizontalOptions="Start"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        BackgroundColor="Orange"
        TextColor="White"
        FontSize="Title" />
    </Grid>
  </Shell.TitleView>

  <!-- .. -->
</ContentPage>
```

This allows you to fully customize the TitleView, add buttons to it, change the font, size and color and so on.

## Title Spacing / ContentInsetStartWithNavigation

It's not possible to change the spacing between the Title and the Menu icon without a [mapper/handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize) or custom renderer.

You can append the following to the mapper of the `Toolbar` somewhere in your code, for example in your *MauiProgram.cs*:

```cs
    Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ToolbarHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("CustomNavigationView", (handler, view) =>
    {
#if ANDROID
        handler.PlatformView.ContentInsetStartWithNavigation = 0;
#endif
    });
```

**Before the change:**

[image]

**After the change:**

[image]

## Burger Menu Icon Color

It's also possible to change the burger menu icon color, but that's already covered in other questions:

[How to get the default shell flyout icon to react when android dark theme is switched on/off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74252720/how-to-get-the-default-shell-flyout-icon-to-react-when-android-dark-theme-is-swi)

[How do you change the color of the burger bar in maui when using shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74937601/how-do-you-change-the-color-of-the-burger-bar-in-maui-when-using-shell/74937887#74937887)

[Change Hamburger Menu Icon in .NET MAUI app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74424845/change-hamburger-menu-icon-in-net-maui-app)

Answer (score 0):

I have a working solution for this here, you could use Shell renderer but it feels too annoying to me personally

A base content page for the template: https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyEffects/blob/dev/Maui.FreakyEffects/Samples/FreakyBaseContentPage.xaml

And its application :

https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyEffects/blob/dev/Maui.FreakyEffects/Samples/SkeletonEffect/SkeletonEffectView.xaml

For people who would like the code directly:

Create a template:

```
 <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="HeaderControlTemplate">
            <AbsoluteLayout>
                <Grid
                    BackgroundColor="{TemplateBinding Parent.NavBarBackgroundColor}"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                    RowSpacing="0"
                    ColumnSpacing="0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="7*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="93*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Margin="15,0,0,0"
                        StrokeThickness="0"
                        IsVisible="{TemplateBinding Parent.IsBackButtonVisible}"
                        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Tertiary}"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                        HeightRequest="30"
                        WidthRequest="30">
                        <Border.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{TemplateBinding Parent.BackButtonCommand}"/>
                        </Border.GestureRecognizers>
                        <Border.StrokeShape>
                            <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="5" />
                        </Border.StrokeShape>
                        <controls:FreakySvgImageView
                        InputTransparent="True"
                        ResourceId="{x:Static constants:Constants.BackButton}"
                        SvgAssembly="{x:Static constants:Constants.SvgAssembly}"
                        ImageColor="White"
                        SvgMode="AspectFit" />
                    </Border>
                    <Label
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="0,0,0,0"
                        FontSize="Medium"
                        TextColor="{TemplateBinding Parent.HeaderTextColor}"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        Style="{DynamicResource HeaderLabelStyle}"
                        Text="{TemplateBinding Parent.HeaderText}"
                        VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    <Border
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Margin="0,0,15,0"
                        StrokeThickness="0"
                        IsVisible="{TemplateBinding Parent.IsContextVisible}"
                        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Tertiary}"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                        HeightRequest="30"
                        WidthRequest="30">
                        <Border.StrokeShape>
                            <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="5" />
                        </Border.StrokeShape>
                        <controls:FreakySvgImageView
                        ImageColor="White"
                        ResourceId="{x:Static constants:Constants.MeatballMenu}"
                        SvgAssembly="{x:Static constants:Constants.SvgAssembly}"
                        SvgMode="AspectFit">
                        </controls:FreakySvgImageView>
                    </Border>
                    <ContentPresenter
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        IsClippedToBounds="True"
                        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                </Grid>
            </AbsoluteLayout>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

In the content page you want it to show up (Should inherit from your base content page):

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <ContentView x:Name="template" ControlTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderControlTemplate}">
    // Your design here
    </ContentView>
 </ContentPage.Content>
```