# Master View with AppShell

Tags: master-pages, maui, .net-maui.shell

How can I use a master view on top of my Shell?

In .NET MAUI app I am using Shell on top of which I need to design a custom status bar. How can I have it as a master view on top of my app shell?

[image]

Comment: by master view do you mean the status bar which shows time, battery and wifi or do you mean the navigation bar which have hamburger menu and title

Comment: @Paramjit he means the hamburger menu. This question gets asked once a week. This week we got it on Monday, so maybe it will be asked more than once.

Comment: yes, I mean a master view where I can have the status bar maybe along with the navigation bar too. so it's common throughout my app.

Comment: @H.A.H. can you redirect me to where it's been asked before?

Comment: @F.F yes, at the bottom of the current page with questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75692967/how-can-i-customize-the-title-in-a-net-maui-flyout-shell-app
And 100 times before that. For some reason none of them get ever marked as duplicates.

Comment: No, this is different. I want something like this below. 

A master page that contains my custom status bar and nav bar along with my Shell.

`<ContentPage x:Name="MasterView">
   <CustomStatusBar/>
<CustomNavBar/>
<Appshell/>
</ContentPage>`

I am not sure if this is something that's even possible cause I have been trying it out myself with no luck.

Comment: You can customize navbar using Shell.TitleView. For status bar the dotnet maui customization is limited to coloring only. Check out status bar behaviour at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/statusbar-behavior?tabs=android

Comment: Yes. but you can't customize the navbar to give it a gradient background color.

and I need a full customized status bar as shown in picture above.

Comment: If you want to custom the status bar, you neet to hide the system bar at first. And you need to make the customized status bar interact with the system, such as the power, signal and so on. It's a hard work.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT That's been done.

Comment: It seems there is no way to put an view on the top of the navigation bar in the contentpage. You may neet to custom the navigation bar and show the UI you want.